# attach an apk file to email on android

Tags: android

Here is my code but I want to pick multiple contacts, so what do I need?

```
 public void selectContacts(View v) {
     Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
     startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Call it multiple times or write your own Contact Picker Activity?